# Converting YAML to JSON with Python: <block end> found

Tags: python, json, yaml

I'm trying to convert the following example `yaml` file into `json`

**test.yaml**

```
- fields: {name: "Test", nr: "000"}
    model: testmodel
    pk: "1"
```

However, calling

```
python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; json.dump(yaml.load(sys.stdin), 
sys.stdout, indent=4)' < test.yaml > test.json
```

returns an error

```
"expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, token.start_mark)
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "<stdin>", line 1, column 3
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "<stdin>", line 3, column 5
```

What's wrong with my yaml-file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong.  You probably meant:

```
- fields: {name: "Test", nr: "000"}
  model: testmodel
  pk: "1"
```