# How to converted indented .yaml files to json using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, yaml

Currently I am working on a project where I'd need to convert multiple .yaml filse to .json in order to work with it.

Example .yaml-file:

```
id: 1
name: Tony
created: ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  zone: utc
  time: 10:00:00
updated: ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  zone: utc
  time: 10:00:01
```

However, when I try to convert it using this script:

```
python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; json.dump(yaml.load(sys.stdin), 
sys.stdout, indent=4)' < test.yaml > test.json
```

I returns this error:

```
expected <block end>, but found '?' in "<stdin>", line 9, column 5
```

**Edit 1:** changed .yaml file example (created_at)

Comment: I might be mistaken, but isn't the indentation 2 in your example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting YAML to JSON with Python: <block end> found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382552/converting-yaml-to-json-with-python-block-end-found)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the yaml file should be like this:

```
id: 1
name: Tony
created:
  zone: utc
  time: '2016-11-24 10:00:00'
updated:
  zone: utc
  time: '2016-11-24 10:00:01'
```

And run this code:

```
with open('test.yaml') as f:       
    dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f) 
    print (json.dumps(dataMap))
```

And you will get :

```
{"updated": {"zone": "utc", "time": "2016-11-24 10:00:01"}, "id": 1, "name": "Tony", "created": {"zone": "utc", "time": "2016-11-24 10:00:00"}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Well, partially.. I made a small mistake in my yaml example. (edited my post). I am this exact error: 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "test.yaml", line 3, column 2.

Comment: @JoshWilliams  Make sure your YAML syntax is correct,this error means your yaml syntax is illegal,have a look at [YAMLSyntax](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your input is incorrect YAML as you cannot have a key/value pair:

```
created: ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

that is not indented, followed by an indented key/value pair:

```
  zone: utc
```

The probable cause for this is that you left out the `!` introducing the tag for a ruby object. You should get rid of the full `ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`.

That you get the message that colons are not allowed in scalars is because PyYAML doesn't support ':' in string scalars (`ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`) even if that colon is not followed by a space. I recommend you update to ruamel.yaml (which supports YAML 1.2 and many more things. Disclaimer: I am the author of that package).
You should also use '.safe_load()' instead of `.load()' (which is not safe to use!)

Given this correct YAML input:

```
id: 1
name: Tony
created: 
  zone: utc
  time: 10:00:00
updated: 
  zone: utc
  time: 10:00:01
```

and running:

```
python -c 'import sys, ruamel.yaml, json; json.dump(ruamel.yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout, indent=4)' < test.yaml
```

you will get:

```
{
    "updated": {
        "zone": "utc", 
        "time": 36001
    }, 
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Tony", 
    "created": {
        "zone": "utc", 
        "time": 36000
    }
```